# Different ways of STATING a theorem.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

The statement of Division Algorithm is like this-

> Given integers $a$ and $d$, $d\ne0$, there exist unique integers, $q$ and $r$, such that
>   $a = qd + r$ with $0\le r<|d|$.

But would it be wrong if I STATE the statement in this way??

> Given integers $a$ and $d, d\neq0$, there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ ,with $0\leq r < |d|$ such 
>   that $a=qd+r$.

Is it incorrect to state it this way?

Would it affect the proof of the Division Algorithm if i state the STATEMENT of
Division 
Algorithm this way?

Comment: It is the same statement

Comment: Why do your think the statements might be different?